# Scikit FDA - Landmark_registration Problem

Tags: python, signal-processing

After a smoothing procedure, I have a problem with the landmark registration in this line:

```
skfda.preprocessing.registration.landmark_registration_warping(fd, land)
```

It return the following error:

```
ValueError: `x` must be strictly increasing sequence.
```

**fd** is a FDataGrid (typical type of data required to represent the function) with 5 samples, while **land** is an array of landmark that I want to align and it is an increasing sequence of points (see below)

```
land <- array([[[0.1  , 0.134, 0.258, 0.292, 0.328, 0.558, 0.602],
                [0.1  , 0.126, 0.23 , 0.256, 0.292, 0.454, 0.474],
                [0.1  , 0.148, 0.25 , 0.278, 0.34 , 0.514, 0.568],
                [0.1  , 0.116, 0.25 , 0.276, 0.298, 0.508, 0.612],
                [0.1  , 0.132, 0.258, 0.286, 0.376, 0.59 , 0.648]]])
fd <-
```

Can somebody help me? I'm using scikit fda package to perform this kind of analysis

https://fda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/preprocessing/autosummary/skfda.preprocessing.registration.landmark_registration.html#skfda.preprocessing.registration.landmark_registration

This is the link to the function that I'm using

Answer (score 0):

1. I had this error when finding my own landmarks. I forgot to pass in the actual domain value at that point (in my case the peak(s) I was wanting to align). Once I did that my error changed to: `ValueError: Sample points must be within the domain range.` Which brings me to my next point:
2. Manually specifying the end result landmark locations allowed the code to run, and from what I can tell "work." I'm not sure if this is a bug, or if I am doing something wrong myself. However, the examples they provide do explicitly state that the end result landmark locations shouldn't have to be specified.

Additionally, the end result landmark locations do not seem to end up at the specified points. They end up at the closest point in the `grid_point` array. This may not be too obvious/a problem for high sample rate data, but for the demo GAIT data scikit-fda provides, there are only 20 sample points so it is noticeably visible that the landmarks do not go exactly where specified. This is also the case for when converting to a basis function as well. One could possibly toy around with the interpolation options and see if it helps.